# ReactJs select page to show to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i want to make a react app that shows specific page due to what i (the owner) chose to the user

EXAMPLE: User is in Home and reacts with my app and the app requires response from the owner/server
i choose to show him the contact page and the app shows the contact page.

I do not know how to explain better sorry

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't include it in the question.

Comment: I did not code nothing i just want to know the example how it works

Comment: That makes your question *off-topic* on [SO]. In here you can post code you wrote and ask why it's not working the way you intended it. You're also supposed to decently document why you believe it should work the way you intended it. From what you showed so far, it appears you need to hire a developer. Or become one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done Via the socket.io (Socket.IO is a library that enables low-latency, bidirectional and event-based communication between a client and a server.)
Which some examples can be found at : https://socket.io/get-started/chat